Latex paragraph indentation missing
I am using \setlength{\parindent}{1cm} and \setlength{\parskip}{0cm} in preamble for consistent paragraph indentation, however when rendering file in pdflatex I have no indentations visible in my chapters.
Most probably I have conflict with one of the packages, but unfortunately I am not able to figure out which one is causing problems.
Could you kindly help me? My aim is to have every (first as well) paragraph indented with 1cm indentation.
My pdflatex code:
\documentclass[12pt, openany, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos} % For positioning the text block
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor} % For background color
\usepackage{pagecolor} % For setting page colors
\usepackage{afterpage} % Necessary for using \afterpage
\usepackage{tikz} % For precise positioning of images
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry} % Set document margins
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % For custom headers and footers
\usepackage{helvet} % Font setting
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace} % For line spacing
% \usepackage[document]{ragged2e} % for left alignment
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{float}

% Compressing - only for pdflatex
\pdfminorversion=7
\pdfcompresslevel=9 
\pdfobjcompresslevel=3
\usepackage{hyperref}
% Set up hyperlinks
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=black,
    filecolor=blue,      
    urlcolor=blue,
    pdfborder={0 0 1}
}

% Custom page styles
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{} % Clear header and footer
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} % Page number at bottom center
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % No header rule
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % No footer rule (optional)
}
\pagestyle{fancy} % Apply fancy page style
\fancyhf{} % Clear header and footer fields
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} % Centered page number in footer

% Define custom colors
\definecolor{mylightblue}{RGB}{173,216,230} % Light blue color definition

% Path to images
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

% Define document parameters
\newcommand{\booktitle}{Smart Structuring: A Guide to Efficiently Managing Data Science Projects}
\newcommand{\bookauthor}{Tomasz Guściora}
\newcommand{\bookdate}{\today}
\newcommand{\authorphoto}{author_photo.jpg} % Add your photo file name here



% Set indentation globally
\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{0cm}


\begin{document}
%\raggedright % to ensure consistent spacing and avoid full-page justification
\doublespacing % Set line spacing to 1.5 from here


% Cover page
\begin{titlepage}
    \thispagestyle{empty} % No headers or footers
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node[anchor=center, inner sep=0] at (current page.center) {
%            \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,keepaspectratio]{}
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{textblock*}{10cm}(\dimexpr(\paperwidth-10cm)/2,\dimexpr\paperheight-10cm) % Centered position for the text block
        \colorbox{white}{\parbox{\textwidth}{
          \vspace{0.5cm}
            \centering
            {\Huge\bfseries \booktitle\par}
            \vspace{0.5cm}
            {\Large \bookauthor\par}
              \vspace{0.5cm}
        }}
    \end{textblock*}
\end{titlepage}

% Clear the background color set for the cover page
\nopagecolor % Ensure the next page after the title page does not carry over the color

% Title page and Copyright
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
    {\LARGE \booktitle}\\[1em]
    {\large \bookauthor}\\[1em]
    {\large \today}
\end{center}
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
    Copyright \textcopyright\ \the\year\ \bookauthor \\
    All rights reserved.
\end{center}
% About the Author
\newpage
\thispagestyle{plain} % Apply page number at the bottom
\begin{center}
    \vspace*{\stretch{1}} % Add vertical space above the photo
%    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{} % Author photo centered
    \vspace*{1cm} % Space between the photo and text

    {\Huge \bookauthor\par} % Author name in large font size
    \vspace*{1cm} % Space between the author name and about text
    
    {\Large About the Author\par} % Section title
    \vspace*{0.5cm} % Space before about text
    
    \begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}
        % Replace this with actual text about the author.
        \normalsize
        Data scientist with a nudge for writing \& joking.
        You can find my work here (if those pages still exist):
\begin{itemize}
  \item[{\faHome}] \href{https://demystifAI.blog/}{Homepage: https://demystifAI.blog/}
  \item[{\faStackOverflow}] \href{https://demystifAI.substack.com}{Substack: https://demystifAI.substack.com}
  \item[{\faTwitter}] \href{https://twitter.com/TomaszGusciora}{Twitter/X: https://twitter.com/TomaszGusciora}
  \item[{\faEnvelope}] \href{mailto:tomasz@demystifai.blog}{Contact me: tomasz@demystifAI.blog}
\end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}

    \vspace*{\stretch{2}} % Add variable vertical space below the text
\end{center}

% Table of Contents
\tableofcontents

% Introduction
\chapter{Preface}
Since the beginning of ages, people have had problems with ordering files on their desktops. You could easily imagine an honest day of work in ancient Egypt, opening your \raggedright{\texttt{Pyramid\_resources}} folder and seeing there something like this:
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep, nolistsep]
    \item \texttt{limestone.jpg}
    \item \texttt{limestone\_v1.jpg}
    \item \texttt{limestone\_v4.jpg}
    \item \texttt{limestone\_v4\_but\_better.jpg}
    \item \texttt{limestone\_v3\_sent\_from\_Anubis\_Final.jpg}
\end{itemize}
\bigskip \par What the hell are you supposed to do with this?! Which limestone should be used for today's construction batch? There is an enhanced version 4 at hand, but I am not sure if Anubis isn't someone who has the final say around here...\par
\end{document}


Erh, \raggedright is a declaration, not a macro that takes arguments.

IMHO this is a kind of XY problem. If you tell us, what exactly you've tried to solve with \raggedright{\texttt{Pyramid\_resources}} we could try to find alternatives for this not working attempt that breaks your whole paragraph layout.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

After the declaration \raggedright (which does not take any arguments), all hyphenation and paragraph indentations are disabled.
So remove \raggedright{\texttt{Pyramid\_resources}} from the example. What was this suppose to do in the first place?

Hi, thank you very much for your answer. I guess I put too much trust in ChatGPT hints :) This exactly resolves the paragraph issue! Originally \texttt{Pyramid_resources} unfortunately renders after right page margin, so I was looking for a way to maintain page layout. I'll have to find another solution for that - I will gladly accept any further hints.
